# How to fix these nginx errors?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx

2024/02/18 18:05:18 [error] 10477#10477: *56 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 185.241.208.97, server: , request: "GET /wordpress/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://localhost/wordpress/", host: "earthpixel.fun"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kimVn.png)

I'm trying to start my site, but it says 502 bad gateway.